# Arduino freezes if I do NOT do Serial.println() at least TWICE

Tags: serial, arduino-nano, platformio

Hii I have a big project, and found this when I tried to remove all the test code.

To summarize:

1. I have a variable that I use as a buffer for string operations called **char internalbuffer[32]** declared in my file **[xstrings.h](https://github.com/Tilation/nanorpg/blob/main/src/xstrings.h)**, it is very important and it is used a lot in the other files.
2. If I call, in Setup, **Serial.println(internalbuffer) twice or more**, the arduino will **run normally**.
3. If I call, in Setup, **Serial.println(internalbuffer) once or not at all**, the arduino **will NOT run** any code.
4. I tried, with no result, referencing in other ways internalbuffer.

You can see the main.cpp file **[here](https://github.com/Tilation/nanorpg/blob/main/src/main.cpp)**. (you can check the entire repo **[here](https://github.com/Tilation/nanorpg)**)

My setup:

- [Arduino Nano](https://nakamaelectronica.com.ar/169-thickbox_default/arduino-nano-5.jpg) (Clone) Old bootloader
- [SSD1306 (Clone) Oled 128x32](https://images-na.ssl-images-amazon.com/images/I/41X4YLwaQXL._AC_SY355_.jpg) with **[ss_oled](https://www.arduino.cc/reference/en/libraries/ss_oled/)** library as controller
- 3 DIY Buttons
- [VS Code](https://code.visualstudio.com/) with [platformio](https://platformio.org/) installed.

I've been trying to fix this myself for 2 days now, but got nothing and I'm pretty new to c++ and arduino, any tips or guidance is accepted.

Edit:

**What I have tried:**

- Replacing the 2 `Serial.println(internalbuffer)` to printing any string, didn't work.
- Instead of the serial prints, add a `delay(x)`, tried from 10ms to 5000ms didn't work either.
- Removing `while(!Serial)` seems to have no effect, so I removed it.

**New things I've discovered:**

- Moving the serial prints out of the `if (rc != OLED_NOT_FOUND)` that checks for the oled initialization is not working, so that's new.
- **There is a special place, that if I place the prints there, the arduino keeps calling setup like it was the loop function or something.**

I´ve created a **[pastebin](https://pastebin.com/eVB6kubV)** showing these last 2 items more clearly.

Comment: what happens if you call `Serial.println("test123")` twice?

Comment: try `delay(10);` instead of the two prints

Comment: Is there a specific reason you have `while (!Serial);` at the start of your code? On a nano it *should* do nothing, but you never know...

Comment: Also note that the SSD1306 OLED display takes *most* of your RAM, leaving you *very little* to play with. There's a very high chance it's failing to allocate its internal buffer and crashing.

Comment: **jsotola** replaced the prints as you suggested, didn't work.
**Juraj** added delay(50) before the 2 jsotola prints, didn't work, removed the jsotola prints and left only the delay(50), also didn't work.
**Majenko**, I've added that while(!Serial) in a desperate moment to fix this problem. Also, I don't think that is, because it runs nice and smooth when the 2 prints with internalbuffer are ran.

Comment: then you have some error in your code, which causes 'undefined behavior'